# How to prioritize specific item data when dropping from a data frame in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, drop

Hi i have a question about dataframe in python

There is a dataframe table as below.
and I want to remove some duplicate data.

1. If all the conditions are the same, remove the item above.  (Jack's case)
2. If all conditions except the name and quarter are the same, remove the David's data(row)

The first is possible, but I don't know how to do the second.

Thank you.

```
drop_df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Name'],keep='last)
```

(input data)

| Name | quarter | math | physics |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | 1Q | 90 | 100 |
| Jack | 2Q | 90 | 100 |
| Kevin | 1Q | 45 | 20 |
| David | 1Q | 15 | 60 |
| Adam | 1Q | 15 | 60 |
| David | 2Q | 40 | 75 |
| Adam | 2Q | 40 | 75 |

(wanted data)

| Name | quarter | math | physics |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jack | 2Q | 90 | 100 |
| Kevin | 1Q | 45 | 20 |
| Adam | 1Q | 15 | 60 |
| Adam | 2Q | 40 | 75 |

better using python dataFRAME

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned a pair of DROP criteria:

1. certain conditions C
2. same conditions C *and* matching quarter

So (2.) is more specific than (1.) -- we
say that (1.) is a subset of (2.)

Begin by DROPping rows using (2.),
then go on to DROP relevant surviving rows using (1.)